# Solving $\gamma = \arcsin{\frac{D}{L}}-\arcsin{\frac{D'}{L}}$ for $L$

Tags: trigonometry

> I am building a computational model when I find I need to solve this equation:
> $$\gamma = \arcsin{\frac{D}{L}}-\arcsin{\frac{D'}{L}}$$
> where $\gamma$, $D$, and $D'$ is known, and I need an analytic solution for $L$.

I tried to move the $-\arcsin{\frac{D'}{L}}$ to the left of the equation, and apply $\sin$ on both sides. But the resulting $\cos{\arcsin{\frac{D}{L}}}$ is really troublesome.

Comment: Hint: $\cos\arcsin x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: $$\arcsin y+\arccos y=\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daoust's hint is super useful!

So the idea is to move $-\arcsin{\frac{D'}{L}}$ to the left side, apply $\sin$ on both sides.

Then use the $\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}$ formula to expand the left side.

Substitute $\cos\arcsin{\frac{D'}{L}}$ with $\sqrt{1-(\frac{D'}{L})^2}$ and solve for $L$.

The analytic solution is

$L=\sqrt{(\frac{D-D'\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma})^2+D'^2}$.

Or, as one of my colleague suggested, apply $\sin$ and $\cos$ on the original equation, then we can solve the two equations for $L$.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Applying the $\sin$ to $\gamma$,  we get:

$sin(\gamma)=\frac{D\sqrt{L^{2}-D’^{2}}} {L^{2}}- \frac{D’\sqrt{L^{2}-D^{2}}}{L^{2}}$,

solving with respect to $L$, we have two positive solutions:

$L=\frac{\sqrt{-2D.D’cos(\gamma)+D^{2}+D’^{2}}}{sin(\gamma)}$;

$L=\frac{\sqrt{+2D.D’\cos(\gamma)+D^{2}+D’^{2}}}{\sin(\gamma)}$.